# Kotlin HttpClient and HttpRequest unresolved reference errors on Intelij-idea

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I can't get references to HttpClient and HttpRequest to import/map properly in my Kotlin code. I'm new to Kotlin, so I might not being configuring the project correctly. I tried this both on Mac and Windows machines, and ran into the same issue.

My Import statements:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Header
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys
import java.net.URI
import java.net.http.HttpClient
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.security.Key
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.HashMap
```

Lines causing issues in inside the main fuction:

```
val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("https://openapi.example.com/example/"))
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer $jwt")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
    .build();
```

I receive unresolved reference errors:

[image]

Configuration:

- Intelij-IDEA with Kotlin (latest)
- Amazon Corretto 17
- Gradle 8.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import `java.net.http.HttpClient` was added in JDK 11 but your Gradle configuration should still uses a lower language level.

Try to open your `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts`, and change your `jvmToolchain` to 17. Reload the Gradle in IDEA.